# Can't switch to another node version

Tags: linux, node.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to use node v0.12 to use with ionic.

But I can't:

```
$ nvm ls
 v0.10.33
 v0.12.7
 ->    system
 default -> 0.12 (-> v0.12.7)
 stable -> 0.12 (-> v0.12.7) (default)
$ nvm alias default 0.12
 default -> 0.12 (-> v0.12.7)
$ node --version
 v0.10.25
```

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Can you help please ?

Comment: did you actualy try `nvm use 0.12`, the command `nvm alias default 0.12` only sets the default as 0.12 so you would need to use `nvm use default` to make it active

Comment: I just did and look : `$ nvm use default` gives `Now using node v0.12.7` and `$ nvm current` gives  `system`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend you to switch from nvm to n module which works better as long as you don't need version older than 0.8.6
I don't think you will encounter problems with it.

```
npm install -g n
```

then

```
n 0.12
```